# EJB 3 JDBC Connection Close in Autocommit false

Tags: jdbc, transactions, ejb-3.0, autocommit

Writing a EJB 3 Service with container managed transaction. If i set autocommit false  perform SQL updates and close the JDBC connection within the EJB transaction,will the transaction be still active and commit after the method completes without any exception with the connection currently closed

Answer (score 1):

If you use CMT and connection from the JTA enabled datasource, then when you call connection.close() the connection is not actually closed but returned to the pool. You should also not change the autocommit with the connections taken from such datasource as they are by default set to false and shouldn't be changed. Yes, transaction will still be active, and will be commited/rollbacked, when the transaction scope ends (it doesn't have to be exactly when this particular method completes, since transaction could be started earlier and this method may only participate in it via REQUIRED, instead of running in separate as with REQIRES_NEW.